# Why does fitsSystemWindows="true" remove padding when the status bar is not translucent?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I know that `fitsSystemWindows="true"` makes Views such as the AppBarLayout align their content properly if the status bar (or navigation bar) is translucent. So it ADDS padding. But I noticed that with a non-translucent status bar, `fitsSystemWindows="true"`actually REMOVES padding and makes the expanded ToolBar shorter. Comparison in the image below. android:fitsSystemWindows="true"Why is that?

[image]

Comment: If it just removed padding then your overflow menu would move as well.  To me these screenshots are expected behaviour. What behaviour were you expecting with it `true` and `false`?

Comment: Well actually I would expect it to make no difference since the status bar is opaque. Why is there a height difference at all? There is none if the status bar is translucent.

Comment: Ah now I get it. fitsSystemWindows is moving it behind the status bar even if its opaque

Comment: Yes .. one doesn't denote the behaviour of the other.

Comment: So is there a point in setting it to true if I don't plan to make the status bar translucent? Is there any other benefit?

Comment: If you have a Navigation Drawer it will go over under the translucent status bar (which is just a tint), filling the screen height (this is a popular use case ).. there are other cases but really this is a design decision, when and when not to use it .. This was introduced in android Lollipop, before it was not possible.

Comment: But it is used in the default ScrollingActivity which has a collapsing toolbar but no nav drawer. And I don't understand why it is set to true there, because the status bar is opaque and it stays opaque. fitsSystemWindows makes it move under there but it is not visible unless I make the status bar translucent

Comment: Then don't use the template, or customise it as you see fit .. It is just a default template after all.

Comment: Well I was hoping to understand the reasoning behind it